# Trouble when installing Ubuntu, not sure where I went wrong

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

-Made a 400 GB partition of free space

-Installed most recent version of Ubuntu

-Using Rufus I booted from a USB

-Normal installation -> Something else

-8000 MB Primary, Beginning of this space, Use as: swap area

-92000 MB Primary, Beginning of this space, use as: Ext4 Journaling file system, Mount point: /home

-18000 MB Primary Beginning of this space, use as: Ext4 Journaling file system, Mount point: /

-I then get this pop up which I assume is an indication of my problem:

```
The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions on the following mount points could not be unmounted:

/cdrom

Please close any applications using these mount points.

Would you like the installer to try to unmount these partitions again?
```

-The installation then begins and gets stuck on "Detecting file systems..." and reads this on the bottom of the installer

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:17: Warning: Source ID 12218 was not found when attempting to remove it

GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)

/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:133: Warning: Source ID 12450 was not found when attempting to remove it

GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

I can copy and paste more from the installer or give any more information if it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you dual-booting?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wan't clear.

Comment: Is your other OS Windows? Is your Machine `UEFI` instead of `BIOS`? Are you planning to install `GRUB`, if so are you planning to install it in `MBR` or `/root`? Try mounting your filesystem using a `live system`, format the partition on which you're trying to install `ubuntu` and re-try.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroing this, but i couldn't find a solution for this online for a while now:

what solved it for me was getting into windows and:

1. Uninstalling UnetBootin from a previous attempt
2. Ejecting "U3 Cruzer" from the nonexistent Cd drive: the usb stick had a virtual cd drive that had it's drivers - Eject this from my computer.
3. Unmount any virtual Iso's, like from daemon tools or other programs.